# Conditional formatting cells based on values on the same row

Tags: excel

Suppose you have an excel file that you use to prepare item descriptions. So in a Sheet, you may have one or more table-like structures, one following the other, with two rows. See image that follows:

[image]

Required information have a star. So in this example, data1 is required, data2 is not. The values for data1 and data2 should be provided in the B column (same row).

I would like to highlight (by changing their background colour), either in column A or in column B, the required cells that are empty.

In the example above, B5 and B7 should be highlighted as they are empty; while B2 should remain white as it contains a value.

Question:
is it possible to obtain this in excel? After playing around a bit, it seems to me it is not possible, but I am less than a beginner with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(FIND("*",A1)),B1="")
```

to check if `A` contains `*` and `B` is empty. Result:

[image]

Or check if `A` equal to *data1**:

```
=AND(A1="data1*",B1="")
```

Result:

[image]

Note that reference must be relative.